# How to setup SAPUI5 Javascript auto-complete in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have tried to install `@types/openui5` but it doesn't work.

ui5.yaml:

```yaml
specVersion: '2.0'
metadata:
  name: openui5-sample-app
type: application
framework:
  name: OpenUI5
  version: "1.78.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure `tsconfig.json`.<sup>[[1]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)</sup> For example:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none",
    "target": "es2018",
    "noEmit": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": ["@sapui5/ts-types"]
  }
}
```